# MUI: Modify appearance of back button

Tags: wpf, modern-ui

How can I easily override the styling of the back button. It's currently buried in `ModernWindow.xaml`, and I'd prefer not to compile in all of MUI into my solution.

```
<!-- back button -->
<controls:ModernButton Margin="8,10,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top"
                       EllipseDiameter="24" IconWidth="12" IconHeight="12"
                       IconData="F1 M 33,22L 33,26L 19.75,26L 27,33L 20.5,33L 11,24L 20.5,15L 27,15L 19.75,22L 33,22 Z"
                       Command="NavigationCommands.BrowseBack"
                       CommandTarget="{Binding ElementName=ContentFrame}" 
                       ToolTip="{x:Static modernui:Resources.Back}"
                       WindowChrome.IsHitTestVisibleInChrome="True" />
```

I just want to make it a little bigger and give it a background color of the current highlight color (i.e. blue).

I have a request to make it look more like the huge blue back button in Internet Explorer.

[image]

Comment: It's just an arrow in an `Ellipse`... just draw one.

Comment: @Sheridan are you familiar with the MUI toolkit? This is a framework style that I can't easily override.

Comment: There was no suggestion of overriding anything... I just suggested that you use a simple `Path` and an `Ellipse` to draw an arrow.

Comment: Are you suggesting that I should basically draw on top of what the UI framework is rendering? That's not what I want.